# Why can UIInterfaceOrientationMask be expressed by array?

Tags: swift, uikit

In UIKit, structure `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` can be expressed by array, like so:

```
var orientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = [.portrait, .landscapeRight, .landscapeLeft]
```

How does it work, if this type doesn't conform to`ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` protocol? It only adopts `OptionSet` protocol, which doesn't seem to conform to `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral` neither.

And also, the only `init()` it has is:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationMask.init(rawValue:)
```

I found out `init(rawValue:)` comes from `RawRepresentable` protocol, but there is no initializer for array literal.

Is there any other way to make it possible to express a type by array literal, or?

Comment: [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset) <- [`SetAlgebra`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/setalgebra) <- [`ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral) :)

Comment: That's it! Where's did the initializer go though?

Comment: Which initialiser? `init(rawValue:)` or `init(arrayLiteral:)`? I'm not sure I understand you

Comment: I mean `init(arrayLiteral elements: ArrayLiteralElement...)`, which is required by `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. It seems like this initializer works, but Xcode doesn't give a hint about it. Also, if I provide values of wrong type for `elements`, Xcode says I need to put label `rawValue` in the initializer. Isn't that weird?

Comment: Yeah, it's because you should never use `init(XYZLiteral:)` initialisers directly; they're only meant to be used by the compiler (hence why they no longer show up in auto-completion).

Comment: How is that expressed in their implementation? Can I mark my own initializers as such?

Comment: I *believe* it's special-cased in SourceKit; but haven't looked into it in any detail. So no, I don't believe you can mark your own initialisers as such.

Comment: You may like to add an answer and get some tasty points :)